# OpenCL: Buffers apparently not being read in

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, gpu, opencl, intel

First time using OpenCL. I've put together a quick program to do vector addition from some various examples found around online. Here is the code.

```
     2 #define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
     3 #include <CL/cl2.hpp>
     4 #include <iostream>
     5 #include <vector>
     6 
     7 int main() {
     8   std::cout << "Getting platforms" << std::endl;
     9   std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
    10   cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
    11   std::cout << all_platforms.size() << std::endl;
    12 
    13   cl::Platform default_platform = all_platforms[0];
    14   std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
    15   default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
    16   std::cout << "Using platform: " <<
    17                default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>() << "\n";
    18 
    19   if(all_devices.size()==0){
    20       std::cout<<" No devices found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
    21       exit(1);
    22   }
    23   cl::Device default_device=all_devices[0];
    24   std::cout<< "Using device: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<<"\n";
    25   std::cout<< "\tType: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_TYPE>()<<"\n";
    26   std::cout<< "\tMax Units: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS>()<<"\n";
    27   std::cout<< "\tMem Size: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE>()<<"\n";
    28 
    29 
    30   //Setting up context
    31   cl::Context context({default_device});
    32   cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);
    33   cl::Program::Sources sources;
    34 
    35 
    36   // kernel calculates for each element C=A+B
    37   std::string kernel_code=
    38           "   void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, global int* C){       "
    39           "       int gid = get_global_id(0); "
    40           "       C[gid] = A[gid] + B[gid];                 "
    41           "       printf(\"%f %f %f \", A[gid], B[gid], C[gid]); "
    42           "   }                                                                               ";
    43   sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(), kernel_code.length()});
    44 
    45   cl::Program program(context,sources);
    46   if(program.build({default_device}) != CL_SUCCESS){
    47       std::cout<<" Error building: "<<program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device)<<"\n";
    48       exit(1);
    49   }
    50 
    51   //Create input vectors and assign values on the host:
    52   const size_t LENGTH = 10;
    53   std::vector<float> h_a(LENGTH), h_b(LENGTH), h_c(LENGTH);
    54   for (size_t i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    55     h_a[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    56     h_b[i] = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    57     std::cout << h_a[i] << " " << h_b[i] << std::endl;
    58   }
    59 
    60   cl::Buffer d_a(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float)*LENGTH);
    61   cl::Buffer d_b(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float)*LENGTH);
    62   cl::Buffer d_c(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float)*LENGTH);
    63 
    64   queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(d_a, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*h_a.size(), &h_a[0]);
    65   queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(d_b, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*h_b.size(), &h_b[0]);
    66 
    67   cl::Kernel simple_add(program, "simple_add");
    68   simple_add.setArg(0, d_a);
    69   simple_add.setArg(1, d_b);
    70   simple_add.setArg(2, d_c);
    71   queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(simple_add,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(LENGTH),cl::NullRange);
    72   queue.enqueueReadBuffer(d_c, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float)*LENGTH, &h_c[0]);
    73 
    74   for (float & ci : h_c) {
    75     std::cout << ci << std::endl;
    76   }
    77 
    78   return 0;
    79 }
```

And the output is as follows:

```
    Getting platforms
    1
    Using platform: Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics
    Using device: Intel(R) Gen12LP HD Graphics NEO
        Type: 4
        Max Units: 96
        Mem Size: 26696065024
    0.840188 0.394383
    0.783099 0.79844
    0.911647 0.197551
    0.335223 0.76823
    0.277775 0.55397
    0.477397 0.628871
    0.364784 0.513401
    0.95223 0.916195
    0.635712 0.717297
    0.141603 0.606969
    0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 5.35055e+37
    9.89438e+37
    2.98535e+37
    3.99268e+37
    2.59261e+37
    4.96527e+37
    3.16024e+37
    1.47755e+38
    7.2566e+37
    1.43212e+37
```

As shown, while the kernel is running, it seems like the buffers A and B are not receiving the values from the vectors on the host.

Answer (score 0):

You copy float numbers to the buffers, but the arguments for the kernel are defined as pointers to the buffers with integer numbers. So, the line 38 must be

```
void kernel simple_add(global const float* A, global const float* B, global float* C){
```